# How can I show/hide just one menu item based on user role?

Tags: 7, routes

I have a single menu item that I would like to show or hide based on user role.

Use case: I have a membership site with paid and free memberships.  In the navigation menu, I want to show a link for users who do not have the "paid" role to the "Upgrade your account" page.  There's no need to limit access; I simply want to show or hide the link.

I know I could make a separate menu and restrict access to that menu block by role, but is there an easy way to do the same for a single menu item link in an existing menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it without an extra module if the "Upgrade your Account" page is a view. Then you can limit access for that view to anonymous users and add the menu entry in that view.

Comment: I use Panels, so I will add it in Panels.  I much prefer this approach to installing an unstable module just for one link.

Comment: yeah, I usually take the same approach, "keep it simple" is a great mantra

Answer (score 5):

You may try [Menu per Role](https://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role)

> This module allows you to restrict access to menu items1 based on user
>   roles. It depends on the Drupal core menu.module—just activate both
>   modules and edit a menu item as usual. There will be a new fieldset
>   that allows you to restrict access by role. The fieldset also appears
>   in the node edit form.

[image]

D7 release is not stable yet its `7.x-1.x-dev`

Comment: D7 is indeed dev, but it worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Another module solution to this that I recently found is [Menu Item Visibility](http://drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility).  While it is still in beta, it actually works in D7 right now, which I couldn't get Menu Item per Role to do.  (I had to keep clearing the cache every time a user saved their profile to rebuild the menu.)